# cURL command failed to delete pull-request from bit bucket with 400 error

Tags: rest, curl, bitbucket

I am trying to delete a pull-request from bitbucket. I am using the following command,

curl -v -u {username}:{password} -X DELETE -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://{bitbucket.com}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{project_name}/repos/{repo_name}/pull-requests/{pull-request_id}

but the command fails with an error code 400. Please find the error:

{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"No content to map to Object due to end of input","exceptionName":"java.io.EOFException"}]}.

I think I am missing something in the rest url. Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the "version" of the pull-request (remember that the pull-request version starts in 0). Add the "-d @-" option to send the version in a here-document.

```
curl -v -u {username}:{password} -d @- -X DELETE -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://{bitbucket.com}/rest/api/1.0/projects/{project_name}/repos/{repo_name}/pull-requests/{pull-request_id} <<EOF
{
    "version": {version}
}
EOF
```